# Test for an object's type being that of objects returned by ctypes.byref (and whether in turn its target is of a specific type)

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to test an argument to see if it is a 'lightweight pointer' as returned by ctypes.byref, and also whether the target of that 'pointer' is of the type I am expecting.

At least 3 possible solutions spring to mind - as in the code below - but I can't help feeling they are all rather inelegant. Examining repr's seems particularly suspect, and even creating my BYREF_TYPE constant is not great. Added to that, I am having to use the _obj attribute of the byref object, which is not public.

```
import ctypes

#Type of any object returned by byref. (c_int is just an example - could have been anything)
BYREF_TYPE = type(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int())) #used by test 1 below

arg = ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_wchar('z'))
target_type = ctypes.c_wchar

#1
print(type(arg) is BYREF_TYPE and type(arg._obj) is target_type)

#2
print(repr(type(arg)) == "<class 'CArgObject'>" and type(arg._obj) is target_type)

#3
print(repr(arg).startswith("<cparam 'P'") and type(arg._obj) is target_type)
```

The above code prints the expected 'True' for each version my test, but surely I must be missing something better?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen - good question! I will _attempt_ an answer: I have a factory function exactly like ctypes.POINTER, except that, for certain custom target types, the returned pointer type's from_param method is patched so that it extends the range of objects that can be passed to a foreign function as an argument. Obviously the correct pointer type should be passed straight through, as should the correct 'lightweight pointer', but everything else is delegated in turn to this custom target type's own from_param method. (If that's as clear as mud, I am happy to post the whole module.)